# Finding co-ordinates between two known co-ordinates

Tags: php, maps, gis

I am trying to get all co-ordinates between two other co-ordinates. I followed [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157693/getting-all-vertex-lat-long-coordinates-every-1-meter-between-two-known-points).

For some reason, when I plot the co-ordinates on a map, it seems inverted. This is a plot of when the functions runs with the following variables:

```
$flightfromlat = 40.63980103;
$flightfromlon = -73.77890015;
$flighttolat = 51.4706;
$flighttolon = -0.461941;
$interval = 100000;
```

I don't know much about spherical trigonometry and such to figure out what could be wrong.
Here is the code:

```
<?php
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {
    $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
    $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
    $dist = acos($dist);
    $dist = rad2deg($dist);
    $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    $unit = strtoupper($unit);
  
    if ($unit == "K") {
        return ($miles * 1.609344);
    } else if ($unit == "N") {
        return ($miles * 0.8684);
    } else {
        return $miles;
    }
  }
function parseFloat($ptString) { 
            if (strlen($ptString) == 0) { 
                    return false; 
            } 

            $pString = str_replace(" ", "", $ptString); 

            if (substr_count($pString, ",") > 1) 
                $pString = str_replace(",", "", $pString); 

            if (substr_count($pString, ".") > 1) 
                $pString = str_replace(".", "", $pString); 

            $pregResult = array(); 

            $commaset = strpos($pString,','); 
            if ($commaset === false) {$commaset = -1;} 

            $pointset = strpos($pString,'.'); 
            if ($pointset === false) {$pointset = -1;} 

            $pregResultA = array(); 
            $pregResultB = array(); 

            if ($pointset < $commaset) { 
                preg_match('#(([-]?[0-9]+(\.[0-9])?)+(,[0-9]+)?)#', $pString, $pregResultA); 
            } 
            preg_match('#(([-]?[0-9]+(,[0-9])?)+(\.[0-9]+)?)#', $pString, $pregResultB); 
            if ((isset($pregResultA[0]) && (!isset($pregResultB[0]) 
                    || strstr($preResultA[0],$pregResultB[0]) == 0 
                    || !$pointset))) { 
                $numberString = $pregResultA[0]; 
                $numberString = str_replace('.','',$numberString); 
                $numberString = str_replace(',','.',$numberString); 
            } 
            elseif (isset($pregResultB[0]) && (!isset($pregResultA[0]) 
                    || strstr($pregResultB[0],$preResultA[0]) == 0 
                    || !$commaset)) { 
                $numberString = $pregResultB[0]; 
                $numberString = str_replace(',','',$numberString); 
            } 
            else { 
                return false; 
            } 
            $result = (float)$numberString; 
            return $result; 
}   

function xrange($start, $limit, $step = 1) {
    if ($start < $limit) {
        if ($step <= 0) {
            throw new LogicException('Step must be +ve');
        }

        for ($i = $start; $i <= $limit; $i += $step) {
            yield $i;
        }
    } else {
        if ($step >= 0) {
            throw new LogicException('Step must be -ve');
        }

        for ($i = $start; $i >= $limit; $i += $step) {
            yield $i;
        }
    }
}

function modf($x) {
    $m = fmod($x, 1);
    return [$m, $x - $m];
}


function getPathLength($lat1,$lng1,$lat2,$lng2){
    $R = '6371000'; //# radius of earth in m, rough estimate but enough 
    $lat1rads = deg2rad($lat1);
    $lat2rads = deg2rad($lat2);
    $deltaLat = deg2rad(($lat2 - $lat1));
    $deltaLng = deg2rad(($lng2 - $lng1));
    $a = sin($deltaLat/2) * sin($deltaLat/2) + cos($lat1rads) * cos($lat2rads) * sin($deltaLng/2) * sin($deltaLng/2);
    $c = 2 * atan2(sqrt($a), sqrt(1 - $a));
    $d = $R * $c;
    return $d;
}

function getDestinationLatLong($lat,$lng,$azimuth,$distance){
    $R = 6378.1; //#Radius of the Earth in km
    $brng = deg2rad($azimuth); #Bearing is degrees converted to radians.
    $d = $distance / 1000; #Distance m converted to km
    $lat1 = deg2rad($lat); #Current dd lat point converted to radians
    $lon1 = deg2rad($lng); #Current dd long point converted to radians
    $lat2 = asin(sin($lat1) * cos($d/$R) + cos($lat1)* sin($d/$R)* cos($brng));
    $lon2 = $lon1 + atan2(sin($brng) * sin($d/$R)* cos($lat1), cos($d/$R)- sin($lat1)* sin($lat2));
    #convert back to degrees
    $lat2 = rad2deg($lat2);
    $lon2 = rad2deg($lon2);

    return [$lat2, $lon2];  
}

function calculateBearing($lat1,$lng1,$lat2,$lng2){
   // '''calculates the azimuth in degrees from start point to end point'''
    $startLat = deg2rad($lat1);
    $startLong = deg2rad($lng1);
    $endLat = deg2rad($lat2);
    $endLong = deg2rad($lng2);
    $dLong = $endLong - $startLong;
    $dPhi = log(tan($endLat / 2 + pi() / 4) / tan($startLat / 2 + pi() / 4));
    if (abs($dLong) > pi()) {
        if ($dLong > 0) {
            $dLong = -(2 * pi() - $dLong);
        } else {
            $dLong = 2 * pi() + $dLong;
        }
    }
    $bearing = (rad2deg(atan2($dLong, $dPhi)) + 360) % 360;
    return $bearing;
}

function main($interval, $azimuth, $lat1, $lng1, $lat2, $lng2) {
    $d = getPathLength($lat1, $lng1, $lat2, $lng2);
    $rapydUnpack = modf($d / $interval);
    $remainder = $rapydUnpack[0];
    $dist = $rapydUnpack[1];
    $counter = parseFloat($interval);
    $coords = [];
    array_push($coords, [ $lat1, $lng1 ]);

    $xRange = xrange(0, intval($dist));

    foreach ($xRange as $rapydIndex => $value) {
    //print $value;
        $distance =$value;
        $coord = getDestinationLatLong($lat1, $lng1, $azimuth, $counter);
        $counter = $counter + parseFloat($interval);
        array_push($coords, $coord);
    }
    array_push($coords, [ $lat2, $lng2]);
    return $coords;
}
        
            $unit="K";
            $flightfromlat = 40.63980103;
            $flightfromlon = -73.77890015;
            $flighttolat = 51.4706;
            $flighttolon = -0.461941;
            $interval = 100000; 
            
            $azimuth = calculateBearing($flightfromlat,$flightfromlon,$flighttolat,$flighttolon);
            $coords = main($interval,$azimuth,$flightfromlat,$flightfromlon,$flighttolat,$flighttolon);
            echo '<pre>'; print_r($coords); echo '</pre>';
?>
```

The resultant co-ordinates when plotted look like this:

[image]

### Update

Ended up using the PHP library PHPGEO (https://phpgeo.marcusjaschen.de/) which solved the problem.

Comment: So, what's wrong with the coordinates? It looks decent on the map

Comment: It plots the start point and then the end point, but the path between them is wrong. As you can see the end point is in england (red dot), but the end of the path goes somewhere in North-west africa